# Magento - Add Some HTML/php/JS on All Pages of my Theme After_Body_Start

Tags: php, xml, magento

I've built a custom shopping cart for my Magento site that sends and API call to Shopify to handle payment.

The problem is I need the template file to load on every page in magento. I thought `after_body_start` would be a good place to put the template, but I cannot get it to load!

My template lives in `\app\design\frontend\rwd\crystal\template\mgw\mwCart.phtml`
and contains php, html and javascript. It was running just fine when I placed the code directly into the header.phtml

Here's the xml in `\app\design\frontend\rwd\crystal\layout\local.xml` which should load the template

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>    
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="core/template" name="mwCart" template="mgw/mwCart.phtml" output="toHtml" before="-" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I'm new to Magento and have read through the tutorials. I also checked out and tried any suggestions I could find.

I've seen this [Magento - Add Some HTML on All Pages of my Theme After_Body_Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327230/magento-add-some-html-on-all-pages-of-my-theme-after-body-start) but did not solve my issue.

How can I get my template to load on every page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close here... It the location of your `local.xml` file that is the problem.  Place the existing file in the following location:

`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/local.xml`

..and it should solve the problem.  If you have an existing subtheme, e.g.  rwd/mytheme, the file would go here:

`app/design/frontend/rwd/mytheme/layout/local.xml`

If you still aren't getting the desired results, check the configuration in `Magento Admin->Configuration->Design->Themes` and make sure that you are indeed using the `rwd` theme.  If all else fails, the `base/default` location would be the last thing to try:

`app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml`

Comment: I'm so sorry I actually left the folder out of the path name. Actual xml path is app\design\frontend\rwd\crystal\layout\local.xml I've updated my question to reflect this. I'm 100% sure this is the theme being used, I've modified and added many other files. Not sure why this one is giving me such an issue.

Comment: You had one thing right though, I put the xml block into `base/default` and it fired right up.

Comment: @Rager - Happy to help!  You might want to check the theme-settings that I mentioned in this post if your local.xml file wasn't being picked up in the theme folder.  It sounds like you'll need to make some changes to apply the theme/subtheme that you are trying to use.